# ligature difference in PDF files as shown by xpdf's pdftotext output?

Tags: luatex, pdf

```
$ cat main1.tex 
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
iffy fig flat office baffle
\end{document}
```

```
$ cat main2.tex 
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
iffy fig flat office baffle
\end{document}
```

I use lualatex to compile the above .tex files. Xpdf's pdftotext gives me the following output.

```
$ pdftotext main1.pdf /dev/stdout
iffy fig flat office baffle


$ pdftotext main2.pdf /dev/stdout
iﬀy ﬁg ﬂat oﬃce baﬄe
```

Could anybody show me how to inspect the PDF output to know why there is such a difference?

Given only main2.pdf is available, is there a way to convert it to main1.pdf?

Comment: They use quite different fonts: the first an open type font with proper ToUnicode settings, the other a type1 fonts. You can't convert the one pdf into the other. Why are you using OT1-fontenc with luatex?

Comment: it is almost always wrong to use `fontenc` with luatex, certainly using OT1 encoding is very odd. What is the intention here, simply not loading the package solves the issue, as you show.

Comment: I am trying to understand the difference in PDFs not the latex code as I have some PDFs generated by others having this problem (without the original source and may not be created by latex, but the above example is the closest that I can create to demonstrate the problem). I would like to fix those PDF files. The latex code just to create example PDF files for demonstration purpose.

Comment: @user1424739 then you are asking the whole wrong question. Mucking around with PDF files' inards is off-topic here, I fear...